# The components are getting unmounted and mounted again if we use switch case, Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render cards based on some condition using switch case, but the components to which I am not subscribed to using the store variable from redux-toolkit is also getting rendered and this switch is causing to unmount and mount the component, whereas when I use jsx instead of switch it's not getting mounted and unmounted again, why?
The scenario is that when I change the value of an object in store this happens, while using switch the whole components unmounts and mounts again.

```
const cardValue = useSelector(state => state.object.value)
// Using switch statement
function SwitchComponent({ condition }) {
  switch (cardValue) {
    case 'A':
      return <ComponentA />;
    case 'B':
      return <ComponentB />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

return (
<>{SwitchComponent()}</>
)

// Using JSX directly
return (
<>
{cardValue === 'A' ? <ComponentA/> : <ComponentB>}
</>
)
```

Comment: Couple questions: 1) is `cardValue` changing? 2) `<>SwitchComponent()</>` would just put text on the screen, so i assume your real code is`<>{SwitchComponent()}</>`. Am i correct? 3) is cardValue ever null?

Comment: 1.) yes cardValue is changing. 2.)Yes correct 3.)not it won't be null, there will be value always present in that variable

Comment: what you saying can not be true. Using JSX still unmounts and mounts those components. If your component type from previous render is different than the one from the current render, it will unmount and mount the current component. Since ```ComponentA``` is not equal to ```ComponentB```,```ComponentA``` unmounts and ```ComponentB``` mounts, this changes each time ```cardValue``` changes.

Comment: Your code example doesn't make sense and I'm pretty sure won't "compile" and run. Can you [edit] to clarify the issue/problem, and fix the code example to be a complete and accurate [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a component via a ternary or switch statement does not have any effect on how React will render them and whether they get unmounted or not in between renders. It seems your issue comes from both statements having different behavior;

```
{cardValue === 'A' ? <ComponentA/> : <ComponentB>}
```

This is basically if "A", render `ComponentA` and in all other cases, render `ComponentB`.

But your switch statement does something different;

```
switch (cardValue) {
  case 'A':
    return <ComponentA />;
  case 'B':
    return <ComponentB />;
  default:
    return null;
}
```

If "A" render `ComponentA` and if "B", render `ComponentB`, and in all other cases render null. Based on this, I am concluding your `cardValue` is not just "A" or "B", but can be another value as well, or possibly temporarily while switching from "A" to "B". To make both statements equal, you could use this for your switch statement:

```
switch (cardValue) {
  case 'A':
    return <ComponentA />;
  default:
    return <ComponentB />;
}
```